# "Column" does not belong to table

Tags: c#, database

Below is my code for this method.  I want to process the Active column in the database I am using but I get this error that "Active" does not belong to table.  It is clearly in the table and I have it defined in the RestartData.cs with the properties.  In the database I have it set as a bit rather than a boolean.  I'm wondering if that may be the problem.  1 is for True and 0 is for False.  I've researched this through Google and can't really find anything on point.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
static List<RestartData> AppRestartList()
        {
            List<RestartData> restartDatas = new List<RestartData>();

            RestartData restartData = null;

            string sqlQuery = "Select RestartTime, ProgramLocation, LastRestartTime, RestartInterval, ProgramServer, RestartIfRunning, ProcessName from dbo.anyDatabase where active=1;";

            //execute sql query
            //execute database reader
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, (SqlConnection)DB.MakeConnection("any_database"));
            DataTable dt;  

            command.Connection.Open();

            dt = DB.ExecuteTable(command, "any_database");

            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                //move stuff from reader into log data, and exp
                //not RestartData restartData = new RestartData();  The RestartData() method is already declared
                restartData = new RestartData();
                restartData.ProgramLocation = Misc.NullSafeString(row["programLocation"]);
                restartData.Active = Misc.NullSafeBool(row["active"]);
                restartData.RestarInterval = Misc.NullSafeInt(row["restartInterval"]);
                restartData.RestartIfRunning = Misc.NullSafeBool(row["restartIfRunning"]);
                restartData.ProcessName = Misc.NullSafeString(row["processName"]);
                restartData.LastRestartTime = Misc.NullSafeDateTime(row["lastRestartTime"]);

                //add restartData to list
                restartDatas.Add(restartData);

            }
            return restartDatas;
        }
```

Comment: That question title makes no sense.

Comment: I used it that way because nothing in Google would return with a search on NullSafeBool, so I did it for the next person who might be looking this up

Comment: But the question/problem has nothing to do with the NullSafeBool() method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you are not selecting `active` column from your query.

```
string sqlQuery = "Select RestartTime, ProgramLocation, LastRestartTime, RestartInterval, ProgramServer, RestartIfRunning, ProcessName from dbo.anyDatabase where active=1;";
```

above query turned into a datatable which will contains the column you are selecting using `select` statement.

Now you are using this datatable and trying to access the `active` column which is not even present in that `datatable`.

So this statement will cause an error

```
restartData.Active = Misc.NullSafeBool(row["active"]);
```

So you need to select the `active` column using your select query.

```
string sqlQuery = "Select Active, RestartTime, ProgramLocation, LastRestartTime, RestartInterval, ProgramServer, RestartIfRunning, ProcessName from dbo.anyDatabase where active=1;";
```

But apart from this I would say that why are you accessing the value of `active` col like 
this

```
restartData.Active = Misc.NullSafeBool(row["active"]);
```

Even you know that this *value will always be `1`*

So better to use it like this

```
restartData.Active = true;
```

Comment: Ok, that was simple, but originally I had it in the select statement but didn't think I needed it there because I was using it in the where.  That change return Active "True', thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I think your actual select

```
Select    RestartTime, 
          ProgramLocation, 
          LastRestartTime, 
          RestartInterval, 
          ProgramServer, 
          RestartIfRunning, 
          ProcessName 
from      dbo.anyDatabase 
where     active=1
```

is fine.

Do note that `active` is not in the select list though, but you are referencing it in

```
restartData.Active = Misc.NullSafeBool(row["active"]);
```

Either change the `SELECT` to include the `active` column or remove the line where you reference it.

Comment: I agree and would suggest going with the latter suggestion (remove the reference).  Since the `SELECT` always returns rows with `active=1`, you can always correctly set the `restartData.Active` field to `true`.